# Registry: Delete key for each local user within system

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I got a certain registry key (created by our software) which needs to be removed on each local user account at some point.
Thus, I try to load the users hive and then use SHDeleteKey (as the key is not empty) to get the job done. 
However, SHDeleteKey always returns LSTATUS 2 (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).

The Registry key for each user is placed under
HKCU\Software\XYZ

First, I set the required privileges within my code, which seems to work (return val is TRUE):

```
    (...)
HANDLE th;
LUID rsto;
LUID bckp;
TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp2;
OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &th);
LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_RESTORE_NAME, &rsto);
LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_BACKUP_NAME, &bckp);
tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
tp.Privileges[0].Luid = rsto;
tp2.PrivilegeCount = 1;
tp2.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
tp2.Privileges[0].Luid = bckp;
BOOL p = AdjustTokenPrivileges(th, 0, &tp, 1024, 0, 0);
BOOL p2 = AdjustTokenPrivileges(th, 0, &tp2, 1024, 0, 0);
    (...)
```

Then I use RegloadKey to load the users hive. 
std::string connection contains the path to the respective ntuser.dat file. username is the local user account name.
So the hive should be loaded under HKEY_USERS\username:

```
    (...)
DWORD result = RegLoadKey(HKEY_USERS, username.c_str(), connection.c_str());
return result == ERROR_SUCCESS;
    (...)
```

Now, I try to delete:

```
    (...)
    k = username + "\\Software\\XYZ";
    result = SHDeleteKey(HKEY_USERS, k.c_str());
```

And now result has value of 2.
But the key exists.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance...

**UPDATED INFO**: 
I realized the problem needs to be somewhere on RegLoadKey.
When I load the hive via command line (REG.exe load "HKU\username" ...), I can see the node "username" under HKEY_USERS within regedit.exe. All child nodes are loaded under that node.
When I pause my program after RegLoadKey, the node "username" is also shown under HKEY_USERS, but the node is visualized as empty, so no child nodes are available.
How can this happen? This problem is driving me nuts.

Comment: Have you tried \\Software\\Wow6432Node\\XYZ?

Comment: It's a 32-bit system, forgot to mention that. Sorry.

Comment: I wrote a small helper EXE to do this (delete key from all profiles), but it has a lot of hard-coded info. I can clean it up and post it later tonight if no one else has provided a solution).

Comment: Thank you very much, but it won't be neccessary. Look at my answer below :S

Comment: Why not simplify and run the code at logon.  The key will not be used until then anyway.  Have it start in startup and it could be as simple as a regedit.exe /s regfile.reg that has a "-" hyphen in front of the key name.

Answer (score 0):

Looked at my code again today and I just saw that I loaded "ntuser.BAT" instead of "ntuser.DAT" (both files exist).

I'm really sorry that I wasted your time. :-/